# Issue with String<List> IndexOutOfBoundsException in Android

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

I have used the following code to extract data from List, when I tried using below code I got `IndexOutOfBoundsException`,

what is the reason for this, can anyone help me to stop the issue

```
            for (int k = 0; k < extraItemEntityArray.length(); k++) {
                        JSONObject objectE = extraItemEntityArray
                                .getJSONObject(k);

                        if ((objectE.getString("Description")) != null
                                && (objectE.getString("Type"))
                                        .equals("E")) {

                            topDescription.add(objectE
                                    .getString("Description"));

                            resultTopping.add(topDescription.get(k)); //exception occurs here
                        }
                    }
```

exception screen shot

[image]

Comment: Post your complete code

Comment: I got it working thanks to all u guys.. I hope I have picked the most suitable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of exception is clear: you're trying to get the element with index which is greater than the list's size. Second, the error arises when the code inside the `if` block wasn't executed for at least one time, in this case `k` becomes greater than the `resultTopping` size, resulting in the `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`.
Probably the easiest way to rewrite your `if` statement and get rid of exception is this:

```
if ((objectE.getString("Description")) != null && (objectE.getString("Type")).equals("E")) {
    final String desc = objectE.getString("Description");
    topDescription.add(desc);
    resultTopping.add(desc);
}
```

Comment: how can I use the this condition because even this is important (objectE.getString("Type")) .equals("E")

Comment: @modabeckham delete everything inside the if statement and put the code I've shown here.

Comment: I deleted but I have 2 conditions inside if, so addition to final String desc = objectE.getString("Description");, i want to use (objectE.getString("Type")) .equals("E") condition as well

Comment: @modabeckham I've updated the answer to show you how your code has to look like.

Answer (score 2):

Check the length of `extraItemEntityArray` and `topDescription` arrays.

`topDescription` length is less than the length of `extraItemEntityArray` and hence it is throwing `IndexOutOfBoundException`

Comment: First, these are not the arrays, but `List` implementations, probably the `ArrayList`s. Second, the error arises when the code inside the `if` block wasn't executed for at least one time, in this case `k` becomes greater than the `resultTopping` size, resulting in the `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @aga the issue is not with the resultTopping arraylist, it is with the topDescription.get(k) arraylist

Comment: @Fahim I got what u saying and I understoon the issue but do u mind helping me with code level please

Comment: @modabeckham will need your whole code... and the proper details what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Fahim yes, you're right, I've meant the `topDescription` here.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the if statement, at least once, the code is not executing the line:

```
topDescription.add(objectE.getString("Description"));
```

Then, normally, when u try to get a value it can be out of the bounds.

If you want to get the latest value always, replace these lines:

```
topDescription.add(objectE.getString("Description"));

resultTopping.add(topDescription.get(k));
```

with the following

```
String desc = objectE.getString("Description");
topDescription.add(desc);
resultTopping.add(desc);
```

Because it s necessarily the same thing ;)

Comment: how can I use the this condition because even this is important (objectE.getString("Type")) .equals("E")

Comment: I didnt get the update :(
since desc is string, doesn't allow me to use (objectE.getString("Type")) .equals("E") as I used earlrier, can you tell me what to do there please